# Android Broadcast receiver: Registering receiver in java code vs manifest

Tags: android

I am planning to register for few events in my broadcast receiver that is registered in java code (not manifest). I need to listen to these events for the entire lifetime of the application. In order to receive the events for whole application lifetime, do I need to hold the partial wake lock for entire application lifetime (As I am not registering in manifest) ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `Activity` or a `Service` running and you called `registerReceiver()` in either one, then you can only expect to continue receiving the broadcasts while the CPU is on.

If you want to receive even while the user is not using the device, then yes, you need to use a partial wakelock.